# Wait for a redux action to finish dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following action creator:

```
export function scrolltoNextItem(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(appendItem(Item));
    dispatch(
      scrollToNextIndex(
        getState().items.length - 1
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Problem is that `scrollToNextItem` runs before appendItem has finished and the scroll position ends up being incorrect. I can prove this is the case by adding a `setTimeout` to make the execution of the script wait for the next tick before running `scrollToNextItem`:

```
export function scrolltoNextItem(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(appendItem(Item));
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(
        scrollToNextIndex(
          getState().items.length - 1
        )
      )
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

How can I wait for the `appendItem` action to finish? In standard react land I would just use the `setState` callback:

```
this.setState({something: 'some thing'}, () => {
  console.log('something is set');
});
```

But `dispatch` doesn't provide any callback functionality.

Comment: How does appendItem look?

Comment: Append item is just a plain action.

Comment: Then it should be synchronous and by the time you reach setTimeout, appendItem is already finished @mikeRifgin

Comment: Take a look at "useEffect" from the Hooks Api, might work for what you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616697/6117565

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always wrap appendItem into a promise and pass `dispatch` as an argument to it

```
const appendItem = (item, dispatch) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do anything here
  dispatch(<your-action>);
  resolve();
}
```

Then you can call it like this from `scrolltoNextItem`

```
export function scrolltoNextItem(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    appendItem(Item, dispatch).then(() => {
      dispatch(
        scrollToNextIndex(
          getState().items.length - 1
        )
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that! Thanks :) I'm assuming you meant to remove the setTimeout from your example above?

Comment: How does this guarantee that `resolve()` is called after the action completes?

Comment: Yes. Actions are normally synchronous, unless you are using a thunk or other async actions http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: @Alvaro you can test that by adding debugger, nice

Comment: I think that can be covered if you use `finally` instead of `then`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but actions are normally synchronous, so the store has updated, but in the case of react, that doesn't necessarily mean that all the components that are pulling values from redux have rerendered with those values.

Comment: This is not a good answer because of Alvaro's comment.

Comment: @Alvaro you can repeat this steps if you use a thunk or something. And use then() like its done with appendItem. Right?

Comment: Why does this have 15 upvotes!?  It does absolutely nothing different.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by using redux-saga, the code will be executed in synchronous why even if we have a call to an api

**ref**
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

redux-saga code :

```
import {put, call, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import api from './api/definition/path';
import {appendItem , doSomeStuff, scrollToNextIndex} from './functions'
import SAGA_STORE_CONST from './saga/actions/constants'

export function* appendNewItem({action}) {
  try {
    // first execution : this start the scroll and put it into redux state
    yield put({
      type: SAGA_STORE_CONST.SCROLL_BEGIN,
    });
    // second execution : this is an asynchronous call to an api to get some data
    const elmtName = yield call(api.getElementName, {params: action.data});
    // third execution : this is a synchronous call to a normal function
    yield call(doSomeStuff, {params: action.data});
    // fourth execution : here we can append our Items
    yield call(appendItem, action.Item);
    // fifth execution : scrollToNextIndex
    yield call(scrollToNextIndex, action.getState().items.length - 1);
    // last execution : when scroll ends
    yield put({
      type: SAGA_STORE_CONST.SCROLL_END,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}

export default function* itemsSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(
    SAGA_STORE_CONST.APPEND_NEW_ITEM,
    appendNewItem,
  );
}
```

**Note:**

```
    yield call // are used to call synchronous or asynchronous functions
```

```
    yield put // to dispatch normal redux actions
```

The call to the redux-saga action can be fired by :

```
    dispatch({
      type: SAGA_STORE_CONST.APPEND_NEW_ITEM,
      action: {data, Item, getState},
    });
```